# PHP - Running exec multiple php files

Tags: php, windows

I'm running a curl script that does data mining; for it to run through all date it takes approx 600 seconds.  So I figured, If I split the load with two or three or etc... threads, I could then split that 600 seconds.

Any suggestions?

I know one way to do this is via windows scheduler, I can have it execute multiple files; but ideally I'd like to have windows scheduler execute (i.e. php-cgi thefilename.php) one single file and have that one exec multiple others.

Any suggestions? THanks,

Comment: Threading isn't a magic "make my computer faster" bullet. You can't just add another thread and reliably half the time it takes to do something.

Comment: Yeah, but a lot of that time is waiting for requests to come back - no CPU usage but the thread is blocked, so starting additional threads makes sense.

Comment: Any suggestions you'd recommend?  The load time is based on cURL running scans on various pages, each which take time.  So I was hoping I could run *i.e.* three "bots" via each on their own process (using php-cgi / php.exe)

Comment: Maybe some third-party program that downloads all data before processing? On *nix I would recommend `wget`, should be something for Windows also

Comment: German Rumm, that wouldn't work, the mining occurs every 5 minutes; and then directly after running it invokes a function to scan and clean that data and input into a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really answering your question but a solution nevertheless. You could create a batch file like this:

```
start php-cgi thefilename.php
start php-cgi thefilename.php
start php-cgi thefilename.php
```

This will create three independent threads.

Comment: So simply adding "start" at the beginning could do that?

Comment: Yes, the `start` command creates a new independent thread from a command prompt.

Comment: This seems to have worked best so far.  Now my next question would be, is it possible to send a variable on any of those lines? so I.e.

Comment: start php-cgi thefilename.php a=0
start php-cgi thefilename.php a=5

Comment: What I'd like to do is tell that same php file to put an offset on the array of urls within.

Comment: Just execute your regular command line and put `start` for it.

Comment: Yes, `start php thefilename.php %1` %1 being the first argument passed to the batch file. If your script takes 3 arguments, you'd use `%1 %2 %3` and the arguments supplied to the batch command would be supplied to each instance of the script.

Comment: Sorry, my eyes saw variable but my brain read argument. Still good to know.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if I'm understanding how to use the %1 etc.. Could you give an example? would that be like "start php-cgi thefilename.php %a=25 ?

Comment: No, let's say the batch file is called `spider.bat` and you would call it like this `spider.bat test`. Then `%1` in the batch file is replaced with `test`, so `start php thefilename.php %1` becomes `start php thefilename.php test`. In other words, %1 is a variable containing the first command line argument, %2 the second, etc.

Comment: Is there a tutorial or so for that?  I'm playing around and trying to figure it out.  If I put (in this case i.e.) "test" after the filename, what would that call within the php file? Should I expect a variable $test?  Appreciate the help!

Comment: No, you can only pass command line parameters with batch. You can read out the command line parameters in PHP with the variable $argv. But this is out of the scope of this question, do some research, and if you still don't know the answer open a new question.

Comment: Awesome, got it figured. Thanks nightcracker

Comment: I just realized, using start eliminates the output log; I.e. filename.php >> log.txt; no longer works. suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck on windows, i.e. you don't have the `pcntl` extension, what I would recommend is to use [curl_multi_*](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) to execute multiple requests asynchronously. This is a good way to get more performance if your bottleneck is the server delays.

Comment: Hmm, I forgot about curl_multi; I don't think it would work though.  My script takes the content after it loads the content via cURL and runs scans on that it self.  This would only work if I could run the function multiple times.  I think it makes more sense to run seperate process/threads, let me know what you think.

Comment: If you have a clearly defined job queue that you can easily split, multiple processes is probably easier to do because curl_multi is not really fun to work with. On the other hand it is more flexible if you're building something like a crawler that builds its job queue along the discovery of content.

Comment: Thank you appreciate it.  You're def right, if it was for directly storing / discovery content it would have worked but because I've got invoked cleaning functions that occur directly on the output it wouldn't work. Thanks again though!