# It is possible to running multiple php files?

Tags: php

I have two different tasks each task is in php file, so I have two php files.
Can I run 2 files at the same time?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  It's possible to execute multiple files at once so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: This may be help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675473/php-running-exec-multiple-php-files

Comment: Yes, I ask if it's possible to execute multiple files at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know exactly what you want, but, I think this cam help you:

**run_files.php:**

```
<?php
require 'run1.php';
require 'run2.php';
?>
```

Where `run1.php` and `run2.php` is the files you want to execute.

**UPDATE**

You have said `the second task will have to wait, and then the user will not get the service he needs`, so, this does not work as you expect.

PHP files are read from up to down, like the tasks (Cronjobs), which run one file than other, so, you can't prevent the time between files execution.

Comment: This would probably run the tasks not simultaneously, but in a serial way. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: That's definitely not the answer. according to "at the same time" in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer for your question is about using cronjob.. You can run php file depends on the time that you specified in the crontab..

Comment: I thought about this thing is that the first task would take a long time then the second task will have to wait, and then the user will not get the service he needs.